# Display fixed Menu onscroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to display a a fixed menu at the top of the viewport when the user scroll's down the page a little.

I am able to achieve this easily enough like this:

```
var myMenu = document.getElementById("myMenu");
function websiteScroll() {
    console.log(window.scrollY);
    if (window.scrollY > 300) {
        myMenu.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        myMenu.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

My personal opinion is that this seems too *resource intensive* because I will be getting `myMenu` and carrying out some conditional testing and constantly applying CSS styling every time the user scrolls! Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Considering your code already achieves the desired result, this question may be more suitable for [**StackExchange's CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead :)

Comment: I honestly dont think there is a better way. When the window scrolls it has to do the check of whether you want to show the menu or not otherwise it would show it/not show it inconsistently

Comment: But all that styling?!

Comment: If you already have the same menu somewhere in the middle of the viewport and you want to fix it on top after user scroll, try css `position: sticky;` with `top: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

use **jquery** and **CSS** for this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
                $('nav').addClass('navsrl');
            } else {
                $('nav').removeClass('navsrl');
            }
        })
    </script>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .5s;
}

nav.navsrl {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
}

nav .logo {
    float: left;
}

nav .logo img {
    height: 80px;
    transition: .5s;
}

nav.navsrl .logo img {
    height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    line-height: 80px;
    color: #262626;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: .5S;
}

nav.navsrl ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #f00;
}

section.sec1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(Home1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

section.sec2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(Home2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

section.sec3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(Hom3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

section.content {
    padding: 100px;
}

section.content h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 2em;
}

section.content h1 {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
</style>
 <!-- Nav Bar  -->
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Organisation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- Nav Bar  -->
    <!-- Sections  -->
    <section class="sec1"></section>
    <section class="content">
        <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="sec2"></section>
    <section class="content">
        <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="sec3"></section>
    <section class="content">
        <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </section>
    <!-- Sections  -->
```

Try this And add Your Images [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryXlU.png)

Answer (score 0):

[A good article on all basic navbar designs.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)

Fixed menu on the top essentially requires it's position to be fixed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0;}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background-color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">
<h1>Fixed Top Navigation Bar</h1>
<h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
<h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```